# Proper Stack Exchange site to consult about personal psychologically related family conflicts

Tags: support, chat, site-recommendation

I like to know is there any Stack Exchange site or chatroom to have another advice about some family conflicts which could be related to psychological problems? (It could not be asked at the Psychology Stack Exchange site.)

**Update:**

The above question is about this situation:

> I (man with Electrical Engineer B.S and 37 Years old from [Iran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran) country) have some self
>   problem which could be related to psychological filed some partly deep
>   depression , almost 14 day being admitted to the hospital for those
>   problems 1 year ago) and corrupted family ( semi divorced mothers (65
>   years) and fathers(75 y), addiction in the father ( bipolar disorder
>   my guess!), brain stroked mother and ...), also these days my sister 
>   found that mother have had breast cancer and have had one surgery now
>   needs to chemo therapy, so we have moved to another city for better
>   medical services.
>
> Consider that this family have had high academical education (father
>   dentist mother B.S as chemical teacher in school, two bother also
>   dentist (24 and 38 Years) and sister (28 Y) is a general doctor.
>
> So i was almost 4 days ago with my little brother, sister and mother
>   at another city for care and help for them, so i have seen that my
>   works don't fit to them, sister is so angry and trying to find out my
>   faults ( like why there is messy or don't close the cabinet doors or
>   ... ), brother ignoring me, so i thought i can handle this situation
>   by myself so sister and brothers also could handle their situation but
>   being with each other in this situation without getting any help (
>   maybe psychology therapy) is not necessary.
>
> I have tried to find out my problems by studying more on psychology
>   but it becomes annoying for them ( because of testing my idea on
>   myself and exporting this idea to them and ... ).
>
> There is one resistance on psychological therapy refuse to be Under
>   control of one therapist for example so i cut their medicine and tried
>   to solve my problem by myself and studying on it)
>
> So there is one resistance on the psychological therapy after seen
>   those medicines
>   ([Risperidone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risperidone) and another
>   pill i forgotten)only block my feeling and don't work on the relations
>   and situations.
>
> Now i know i can not solve this condition by myself and in other way
>   there is big resistance for the psychological therapy, it would do
>   when the situation becomes hard like deep depression happens again on
>   me or another huge problem, but until that situation our ways would be
>   no Refer to a psychologist, may be from the father scared about
>   opening addiction problem which have a huge fight on this idea and
>   from others would be said yourself don't go for the therapist , so why
>   us. (really i go almost every 3 months to Psychiatrist and saying i am
>   not eating those pills but have these concerns so i get some advice
>   from him, but don't go for Psychiatric counseling.
>
> So now i am another town and doing myself life, but when contact with
>   my sister, she said i don't want to hear your voice and I hate all of
>   you, so i write here to have your advice about this condition.
>
> I decide not go with them  other town for 17 next days until little
>   brother would go for his final thesis in university when being there
>   is not helpful for them and annoying them, also when not to be there
>   also harming sister! so i was thinking say to here you can go also if
>   have bad feeling, and i would do mother works (‌i have done it before
>   !!), but i think father or other brothers would force to not to do it
>   by your self! but i think it would be the right choice if don't decide
>   to solve the problem by psychotherapy or using other ways that could
>   work.
>
> Now i am thinking that the sister is angry because of these forces, if
>   yes why don't solve it by a psychotherapists (when she is a doctor
>   also!).
>
> Anyway, i asked here to know about next move when after 17 next days,
>   for me and family? if you like to say about what would do if be in
>   this situation, or about your experiences of this kind of situation.
>   (you know have sharing experiences with comments could concern the
>   family attention to the there is ways to ...)

**New update:**
Because of my bad English skill to explain the problem at above and miss understanding like this:

> :54430758 I must admit it's a bit hard to read. Let me try and
>   summarize it, let me know if I got things wrong: You've had some
>   mental health issues in the past. Your mother got breast cancer, so
>   you moved with her, your sister and brother to a different city for
>   medical care and to support her. Being together, your sister is
>   commenting on your faults, and your brother is ignoring you. You're
>   skipping therapy to be together? Now you're in a different town again,
>   and you called your sister but she was angry at you. In 17 days, your
>   brother will graduate and you expect to see your sister and family
>   again, and you'd like some sort of help with that? @Magisch Same old.
>   Procrastinated on a bit of work today by writing an answer, though I
>   did most of it during a very boring meeting :) I may need to go
>   shopping this afternoon too. And I got an e-mail about a bug report
>   that was lost in a flurry of e-mails about review comments a week ago,
>   which I'll look into today. After that, I have a long weekend.

I summarized of above text as this :

I have some psychological problem and my mother have had cancer, so ewe have moved to another town for better medical care system on there, so my sister become to angry as be before and trying to Criticism of me for little things to release herself, and my bother ignoring me in home so i decide to leave them alone and know those can handle this situation, but sister is still angry and know when i came back to there town after 17 next day ( when my brother will go because of his university courses), again my sister will be angry, so i will suggest therapy and the others will forcing on me to shut up and don't say anything, but again this hard situation will be remained again and i will say to sister you could go to our house i another city but others (father, mother and brother ) would force on me to don't change anything you, and shut up.

So i asked about **your suggestion**, and maybe show your suggestion about how to solve this situation to **them**.

Thanks.

Comment: interpersonal skills?

Comment: so i get this SE site from your comment :[interpersonal](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/), Thanks @Luuklag

Comment: Hey el-ss! This is pretty vague, so there's a lot that *could* fit on Interpersonal Skills, and there's a lot that might not... Since you don't have enough reputation yet to use our Sandbox, I'd like to invite you to drop by our [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61165/the-awkward-silence) if you have any questions, and we might help you to refine your question into a suitable shape!

Comment: You must not rely on anonymous advice you might get on the internet. You must not take such advise as means to cure any psychological  disorder you might have. The ***ONLY*** thing you can do is go to qualified psychologist and be treated. Any other way, especially listening to advice on the internet, no matter where and from whom, might make things much worse for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stack Exchange sites don't offer personal advice (there's a reason there are professionals for that, and your family relations are probably too important to trust to random strangers on the Internet).

It may take some skill, but I can imagine you could frame your question in such a way that it's on-topic for [Interpersonal Skills Stack Exchange](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/), the site @Luuklag mentioned in the comments. That community has a fairly extensive [Help Center article](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about what is on-topic there and what not, and what details you should include to get a good answer. Note that most "What should I do" questions are off-topic there: [Are "what should I do" questions on topic here?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1310/321)

> Anyway, i asked here to know about next move when after 17 next days, for me and family? if you like to say about what would do if be in this situation, or about your experiences of this kind of situation.

I'm afraid that's exactly the kind of questions Interpersonal Skills (or any other Stack Exchange site for that matter) is *not* meant for. Too much room for opinion-based answers...